# How can I pass List params in IHP forms?

Tags: haskell, ihp

I am trying to make a multiple selection part of my form in IHP. Currently trying to solve it with multiple checkboxes about like this in the View.

```hs
renderIngredientSelection :: Ingredient -> Html
renderIngredientSelection ingredient = [hsx|
    <li>
        <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" value={(get #name ingredient)} />{get #name ingredient}
    </li>
    |]
```

So the browser tool of the network log says it's properly sending a request like this.

```
barcode=5555555555555&name=Pancake&ingredients=milk&ingredients=egg
```

But in the controller, the `param` function will only catch the first `ingredients` parameter.

Is there any way to catch all these parameters in the controller? I see in the network log, there is created a list of tuples containing all the parameters, including both the `ingredients` parameters. How could I access this and map it into a list like `["milk", "egg"]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`allParams`](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/api-docs/IHP-Controller-Param.html#v:allParams) to access the full request parameters you see in the logs.

For a request like:

```
barcode=5555555555555&name=Pancake&ingredients=milk&ingredients=egg
```

We can use the `allParams` like this:

```hs
action MyAction = do
    let ingredients = allParams
    -- ingredients = [("barcode",Just "5555555555555"),("name",Just "Pancake"),("ingredients",Just "milk"),("ingredients",Just "egg")]
```

We still need to filter this list to only return the ingredients values:

```hs
action MyAction = do
    let ingredients = allParams
        |> filter (\(paramName, paramValue) -> paramName == "ingredients")
    -- ingredients = [("ingredients",Just "milk"),("ingredients",Just "egg")]
```

Now we need to map this key-value-map to only the values. Because the value is a maybe (like `Just "milk"`), we'll use `mapMaybe` instead of `map`. `mapMaybe` throws away all the `Nothing` values and unpacks the `Just`:

```hs
action MyAction = do
    let ingredients = allParams
        |> filter (\(paramName, paramValue) -> paramName == "ingredients")
        |> mapMaybe (\(paramName, paramValue) -> paramValue)
    -- ingredients = ["milk", "ingredients"]
```

We have a `[ByteString]` now. Most functions we're dealing with expect a `Text` instead of a `ByteString`, therefore let's do a conversion using `cs` *(cs is short for convert string)*:

```hs
action MyAction = do
    let ingredients :: [Text] = allParams
        |> filter (\(paramName, paramValue) -> paramName == "ingredients")
        |> mapMaybe (\(paramName, paramValue) -> paramValue)
        |> map cs
    -- ingredients = ["milk", "ingredients"]
```

### Moving it to `Application/Controller/Helper.hs`

For a nice code structure I'd move this function out to `Application/Controller/Helper.hs` like this:

```hs
module Application.Helper.Controller
( ...
, paramList -- Don't forget the export :)
)

paramList name = allParams
        |> filter (\(paramName, paramValue) -> paramName == name)
        |> mapMaybe (\(paramName, paramValue) -> paramValue)
        |> map cs
```

And then use it in the controller like this:

```hs
action MyAction = do
    let ingredients = paramList "ingredients"
```

All the functions in `Application.Helper.Controller` are automatically available in our controllers.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't spot the allParams function in the API docs  Thank you, this blueprint works exactly like I wanted it to.